# Handling sign-out from Firebase without getting permission errors

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

In my Angular/Firebase app, I have a user service which supports sign-in and sign-out. After sign-in, I retrieve app-specific data for the user from my Angular database. The service publishes an observable called `appUser$` which contains the current user object (or `null`, if no-one is signed in). Things look like this. I'm using `switchMap` to switch between different observables for my app's user data as users sign in and sign out.

```
constructor( 
  private angularFireAuth: AngularFireAuth,
  private angularFireDatabase: AngularFireDatabase
) {
   this.appUser$ = this.angularFireAuth.authState
     .map(user => user && user.uid)
     .switchMap(uid => uid ? this.angularFireDatabase.object(`/users/${uid}`) : 
       Observable.of(null);
}

signOut() { return this.angularFireAuth.auth.signOut(); }
```

The problem with this is that the instant sign-out occurs, the permissions for accessing the `/users` node in the database are lost, generating an permission denied run-time error. To deal with this, I tried creating my own `Subject` for Angular `User` and zero it out before calling `signOut`. I thought that this would trigger the `switchMap` and somehow cancel the pending object observable for the previous user's app data, thereby preventing the permission denied error.

```
user$: Subject;

constructor( 
  private angularFireAuth: AngularFireAuth,
  private angularFireDatabase: AngularFireDatabase
) {
   this.angularFireAuth.authState.subscribe(this.user$);

   this.appUuser$ = this.user$
     .map(user => user || user.uid)
     .switchMap(uid => uid ? this.angularFireDatabase.object(`/users/${uid}`) : 
       Observable.of(null);
}

signOut() { 
  this.user$.next(null);
  return this.angularFireAuth.auth.signOut(); 
}
```

But the same permission problem persists, even if I delay the call to `signOut`. It seems as if somehow the observable created by `this.angularFireDatabase.object` is somehow still "alive" even after the `switchMap` should have switched to the `Observable.of(null)`, and Firebase is still unhappy about losing permissions to access it.

I could trap or suppress this error somehow, but is there some simple way to deal with this situation?